# How long are magic cards actually "printed"/"In production"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Basically I'm wondering how long Magic cards are actually printed/in production. IE: Being made.

I would assume it's just whatever is in the standard block? but it could go further back. Wizards has a reprint policy, but it has more to do with specific cards and not decks as a whole.

Thanks!

Comment: depends on how the set sells, usually there is a second print run, sometimes a third...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot speak towards any product printed and packaged for general consumption (ie. booster boxes, theme decks, special sets such as Planeshift or Commander, and Fat Packs, among others), but Wizards *does* list redemption guarantee dates for sets redeemable from Magic: the Gathering Online.

From their [Magic Online Product Release & Redemption Schedule](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Digital/MagicOnline.aspx?x=mtg/digital/magiconline/calendar#magiconlineproductreleaseredemptionschedule):

`As a general rule, Magic Online sets will be available for redemption roughly one month after they are released. If a redeemable set runs out of stock before its Redemption Guarantee Date, the set will be reprinted. After a redeemable set's Redemption Guaranteed Date has passed, such set will be available while supplies last or until its Cutoff Date, whichever comes first. All cutoff times are 9:00 AM.`

At the very least, it appears that Wizards will print new product at least until approximately one month after a set rotates out of the Standard Format (if the initial print run is not sufficient to meet the Magic: Online redemption demand.)

Comment: Here is [an article](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/174) on wizards.com which explains how a card goes from conception to print. Magic the Gathering cards are printed by a company called [Carta Mundi](http://www.cartamundi.com/). I was going to theorize that sets are just printed in one run and warehoused for distribution, but your answer has specific details on how long a set is printed. It seems you only have to look at Magic Online Redemption Guarantee Dates to see how long a set is in production. Good answer.

Comment: I think if that ever actually happened someone in supply chain management would be looking for a new job :)

Comment: @Affe I agree. Though if a set turned out to be surprisingly very popular, I can see there being more print runs within the window. Similarly if a set bombed, there probably wouldn't be reprints and a good deal of surplus stock (like Fallen Empires back in the day).

Comment: I do know for a fact that the Innistrad set stopped being printed several months before rotating out of standard, meaning your final statement is incorrect.

Comment: @bengoesboom My final statement is predicated upon Wizards following their own policy, which means that if they run out of redeemable product before 10/31/13, they **will** print more Innistrad.